# High performance XML parsing in C++

Tags: c++, xml, parsing

Well a lot of questions have been made about parsing XML in C++ and so on...
But, instead of a generic problem, mine is very specific.

I am asking for a very efficient XML parser for C++. In particular I have a VERY VERY BIG XML file  to parse.
My application must open this file and retrieve data. It must also insert new nodes and save the final result in the file again.

To do this I used, at the beginning, rapidxml, but it requires me to open the file, parse it all (all the content because this lib has no functions to access the file directly without loading the entire tree first), then edit the tree, modify it and store the final tree on the file by overwriting it... It consumes too much resources.

Is there an XML parser that does not require me to load the entire file, but that I can use to insert, quickly, new nodes and retrieve data? Can you please indicate solutions for this problem of mine?

Comment: "High perfomance xml" - isn't that an oxymoron?

Comment: From one of the creators of this site, why XML is not a database: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want a streaming XML parser rather than what is called a DOM parser.

There are two types of streaming parsers: pull and push. A pull parser is good for quickly writing XML parsers that load data into program memory. A push parser is good for writing a program to translate one document to another (which is what you are trying to accomplish). I think, therefore, that a push parser would be best for your problem.

In order to use a push parser, you need to write what is essentially an event handler for parsing events. By "parsing event", I mean events like "start tag reached", "end tag reached", "text found", "attribute parsed", etc.

I suggest that as you read in the document, you write out the transformed document to a separate, temporary file. Thus, your XML parsing event handlers will need to be written so that they are stateful and write out the XML of the translated document incrementally.

Three excellent push parser libraries for C++ include [Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/), [Xerces-C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/), and [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/).

Comment: Whether you use a pull or push SAX parser, the end result is the same.  Both require event handlers be used while the XML data is being parsed in chunks.  The only difference between them is that a pull parser automatically retreives data from a source you specify (like a file), whereas a push parser lets you obtain the data yourself and pass it to the parser (in this regard, a pull parser uses a push model internally).  Both parsers have the same kind of internal logic though - given a chunk of data, parse it and fire events as needed, then pull/wait for the next chunk and repeat...

Comment: ... so, your SAX event handlers can extract the data as needed in real-time while the XML is being parsed in chunks, and then you can write the supplied data to a temp file, writing new data where needed, then replace the original file with the temp file when finished.

Comment: Also, I use libxml2 in my C++ code, works great.  It supports both DOM and SAX (pull and push) models.

Comment: @Remy: While it is true that pull and push parsers are very similar, I am mainly pointing out two scenarios where I think that a pull parser or a push parser should be used because of convenience. In my experience, either parser type can be used for the two scenarios, but I have found it easier to use a pull parser instead of a push parser in certain cases.

Comment: @Everyone: Well Thank you, they are wounderful suggestions... I just have a question, here: http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html if you slide down a bit you can see a table stating performances for RapidXml vs the world... well it says that RapidXml is the fastst, even 100x than Xerces... where is the trick??????? how's that possible... is it really Xerces that bad? Can Xerces parse my file faster than RapidXml?

Comment: @Andry: Xerces provides a DOM parser implementation. I am guessing that RapidXML (a DOM-style parser) is comparing its timings against that.

Comment: @Andry: Another reason why RapidXML's parser may be faster than Xerces' DOM parser is that RapidXML does not appear to be a true DOM parser; from the RapidXML API docs, it does not appear that its `xml_document` type implements any level of the W3C DOM standard. DOM requires overhead, which may be the main reason why RapidXML is faster than Xerces' DOM parser.

Comment: Even better use StAX parser instead SAX, but only few StAX parsers available for C++

Answer (score 6):

Search for "SAX parser". They are mostly tokenizers, i.e. they emit tag by tag without building a tree.

Comment: @Andry they say Xerces has/supports SAX, so probably this will work for you.

Answer (score 5):

SAX parsers are faster than DOM parsers because DOM parsers read the entire file into memory before building an in-memory representation of the XML document, whereas a SAX parser behaves like an event listener and builds the document as it reads in the file. [Go here](http://www.w3.org/DOM/faq.html#SAXandDOM) for an explanation.

As you mentioned [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) is a good C++ SAX parser.

I would recommend looking into ways of breaking the XML document into smaller XML documents as that seems to be part of your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, here is one off the beaten track, I looked at this, but haven't really used it myself, it's called [asmxml](http://tibleiz.net/asm-xml/). These boys claim performance bar none, downside, you need x86 assembler.

Comment: @downvoter, please explain? I was just highlighting an unusual parser that claims better performance than most major parsers out there, what's wrong with what I've said?

Comment: I think the downvote was because the OP specified a parser in C++.

Comment: @Chris, hmm, the parser is written in assembler yes, but it's meant to be used in C++ applications! I would not have bothered posting it otherwise! :(

Comment: I actually agree with you. Was just giving an educated guess as to why the downvote. I put it back to 0 for ya too. :-)

Comment: One good reason for downvoting might be that this is a 32-bit only parser and cannot be linked to 64-bit applications. See the [FAQ](http://tibleiz.net/asm-xml/faq.html). It also implements a subset of xml.

Answer (score 4):

If you really seek **high performance XML stream parser** then [libhpxml](http://www.abenteuerland.at/libhpxml/) is likely the right thing for you.

Answer (score 2):

I’m convinced that no XML library exists that allows you to *modify* a file without loading it first. This simply isn’t possible because files don’t work that way: you cannot insert (or remove) in the middle of a file. You can only *overwrite* a block of identical size, or *append* at the end. But your request would require to append or remove in the middle of the file.

Reading only parts of an XML file may be possible. But *writing* … no way.

Comment: Well no... it is possible Ordering is not needed, it is performed later, by tokenizing file, you can locate a node and wherever inside it insert the new node... no need to get the entire file... no?

Comment: @Andry: wrong. Ordering *is* needed in an XML file. It’s possible that you don’t need it but the XML standard mandates that the ordering of the nodes is fixed. Furthermore, tokenizing (in particular finding the matching *end* token) pretty much involves reading the whole file.

Comment: Thank you... yes you're right... then things get much harder... I wonder how libraries in c# or high level languages can parse very big xml files in few milliseconds....

Comment: @Andry: interesting question. Perhaps they can’t … i.e. they just “pretend” to parse the whole file but in reality wait until you actually access a given node, and only *then* parse the node fully. But once again, as soon as you try to modify (and write back to disk) any node, the whole file has to be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Go for template libraries as much as possible, like Boost::property_tree or Boost::XMLParser or POCO::XML and Folly has XML Parser in it.

Avoid old C libraries, it all old code designs.

Answer (score -2):

someone say QtXML module is high performance for huge XML files.